# Conver current jQuery code to valid vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code, but I need to convert it to vanilla Javascript because the project I am working on is not using jQuery
Here is what I have tried, but it is not working. I am unsure for all of these changes that I have made

```js
// My current jQuery code
$('#category-2 ul li').each(function() {
  $(this).find("ul.top-menu").parent().remove();
});
$('#category-2>a').html("Produkte");

// Vanilla JS
document.querySelectorAll('#category-2 ul li').forEach(function() {
  this.find('ul.top-menu').parentNode().removeChild();
});
document.querySelectorAll('category-2>a').innerHTML="Produkte";
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML part of this code, so we can get a good reference of the problem?

Comment: Could we have the HTML please ?

Comment: Here is the HTML: https://codepen.io/john534/pen/jOWwxgL

Comment: Add the HTML to the question please, not just via an external link.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code. One is that in the function you are using the **this** keyword as it would be in a **class**, but in **functions** the this keyword does not refer to what you would expect it to be. Instead use parameters from the forEach function: item, index, array, thisArg can be used.

The second problem is that in Vanilla JS there is no find() method so I would suggest implementing a ternary operator (one line if statement) to check if the className or the id includes what you are searching for.

I'm not sure what items are you searching for without the html it is hard to tell, but it would look something like this:

```
// Vanilla JS
document.querySelectorAll("#category-2").forEach(item => {
  item.className.includes("top-menu") && item.parentNode.removeChild();
});
document.querySelectorAll("#category-2").forEach(item => {
  item.innerHTML = "Produkte";
});
```